# Infinite scroll a canvas with a tiled map without redrawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been working in a game engine for about 6 days straight, retaking everything I've learned from making games back in the old DOS days. However, back then there was double-buffering and you could simply redraw everything at blazing-fast speed. Alas, in HTML5 it's another story.

So far, my engine has "layers" which are canvases put one over another, at 0,0 location, and I draw their context one over another at screen coordinates 0,0. This means, you draw in a layer and the layer gets drawn on the render phase (if it mets a few conditions, of course).

I've managed to make a routine to draw a tiled map on a canvas, and using -> [this](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/smooth-scrolling-a-tile-map-r743) <- article I managed to make it scroll by redrawing on each frame. It all works fine and dandy when you use 320x240, but when I increase it to 640x480 and double the tile count, it slows down like hell.

So I came up with this idea (only horizontal scroll for this example's sake), by using a slightly larger canvas:

1. Draw the canvas with all the tiles and offset its x position by the camera's X pos.
2. If camera position (relative to first drawn tile) > tile_width

   1. Redraw entire canvas, increasing 1 to the starting X tile AND
   2. Reset canvas's X position to zero

This way, I would only redraw the canvas everytime a scroll would be happening, and with some optimization, I could even redraw only the edge tiles instead of the entire canvas (which is the idea anyways).

So my question would be: How would I make this in code?! it could be I'm tired from working on this engine for six days straight, but I just don't see it. Also, what puzzles me even more: How to draw the edge tiles without affecting the rest of the canvas? :(

I can show some code, but I think I can do with a small jsfiddle example I can adapt to my own code. However if you really need to see code, I might make a small sample just for this. Be aware though, my drawing code is just an adapted copy of the article's code (for testing the scrolling) so you can assume I have no tilemapping code written. I have, but I bet I'll need to rewrite it for this case xD.

Thanks in advance!
- DARKGuy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I finally managed to do it and solve my own problem - however, it's faster but still jumpy as my previous attempt. If anyone's interested please ask - but since I didn't even got a single comment I think nobody was anyways.

Here's the final working solution at [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71583/html5-dynamic-canvas-grid-for-scrolling-a-big-map)